# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop change hot key doesn't working

Tags: 16.04, unity

After a Ubuntu 16.04 package update the desktop change hot key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> / ...) and the maximize on monitor board edge (when I, holding the window on title bar, going close the monitor edge) started to not work.

I tried to restart the \org\compiz registry and some configuration folders and nothing. Also restarted the system.

Is this a version issue or can I restart some specific service? I am using the already installed unity desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the reason. But, installing `compizconfig-settings-manager` I was able to get the configuration of other Ubuntu and restore the functionalities.